# typescript How do I use a condition type that does not match 'any' type?

Tags: typescript

I am using a condition type to filter certain fields in my object, but it still matches a field with the type `any`

Is there any way to avoid this? I only want to filter types with {visible: boolean}, and it should not match the `any` type.

```js
export type Column = {
    value1: any;
    value2: string;
    value3: {
        visible: boolean
    },

    value4: {
        visible: boolean
    }

}

type VisibleFieldOnColumn<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as NonNullable<T[K]> extends { visible: boolean }
    ? K
    : never]: T[K];
};


type Test = VisibleFieldOnColumn<Column>;
//    ^?

// i want to filter visible field but not include `value1:any`

const v:Test = {
    value1:'',  // how to remove value1
    value3:{visible:false},
    value4:{visible:false}
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDCmA8AcHsCcBcAE8CelSIMLQDYFcBbAO0QF5EBvYRGxANwEN9QBGALkQaJQG5rbGzAEwcAzvFgBLIgHM+tekzygAzByoKFdSaMkAjHKA57ouUF340AvgBoQWpaAAs6y5u26DRxCbMWFViCBwKjoiABqOvqGAGKSoDgAJgDyRNj4xAA8ACoAfGSUbgDaANKI0ogA1qAo0ABmiNmcoogActBErXg4OAxeOaUAuvkQ8KBEiS0U9FFexqaGXIiBCgD8iCVuHESgdKCwgxzZQ3xWfCChGNmg4gWRnrHxSanphESZr8S5fAD0PwoAPVWID+5UQAHcuEh4NBEHVJDgxrAZg8MPCEokfHgkERoEhpABjfCJDAAA0EynYXBQpJABI6tzobGut3IGgEjnYAHIuTYaKCABbQcHIWGwUAEaB7RTMFhuCmqNgUDzRIx1JiiUC2eWOFzK2aGNjqnCawJWIA)

Comment: There are various tricks you can use to detect the `any` type (see the linked q above for one possibility).  But the point of `any` is that it matches everything (even when such matches are unsafe), so `any` really does match `{visible:boolean}`. If you don't like that, the right answer is to avoid `any`, not to try to force the type system to treat `any` differently.  In some sense `any` is a master key and you're trying to modify a lock so that it won't accept it.  But that's the whole point of the master key, and you should be discouraging its use rather than messing with all the locks.